# Specializing types from namespace std based on user-defined concepts

Tags: c++, c++20

It is written in many places (for example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std)), that specialisations of types from `namespace std` are only allowed if the specialisation *"depends on user-defined types"*. Does this definition in the standard explicitly exclude to specialise `std` types based on user-defined concepts?

For example, is this allowed?

```
namespace std {
  template<MyConcept T>
  struct hash<T> {
    size_t hash(T const& v) const { ... }
  };
}
```

This would greatly simplify many specialisations in my code where I have a lot of different but similar classes adhering to the same concept which can be hashed all in the same way.

Comment: Can you be sure that only user-defined types satisfy those user-defined concepts?

Comment: Yes, I can. But is this what the standard means?

Comment: contrast, say: `template <typename T> concept NotSafe = true;`. Adding a specialisation constrained to that wouldn't be legal, as that specialises `int` and `std::string` etc

Comment: Of course, but *if* the concept only holds for user-defined type, hence the specialisation *semantically* only involves user-defined types, is it ok? Or it must be that the specialisation *syntactically* involved user-defined types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general rule we have, in [[namespace.std]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std) is:

> Unless explicitly prohibited, a program may add a template specialization for any standard library class template to namespace std provided that (a) the added declaration depends on at least one program-defined type and (b) the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template.

For this specialization:

```cpp
template<MyConcept T>
struct hash<T> { /* ... */ };
```

If it is the case that (a) for all `T` that satisfy `MyConcept`, `T` depends on at least one program-defined type and (b) this specialization meets the requirements for hash (i.e. it's invocable, swappable, satisfies the normal hash requirements, etc.), then this is fine.

By depends on at least one [program-defined type](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.prog.def.type), it's not just that it's like `my::Type`, but it could also include `std::vector<my::Type>` and `std::tuple<int, char, my::Type*>`, etc. As long as something in there somewhere is program-defined.